# Как проверить наследование классов в Python?

Tags: python, ооп, классы

У меня есть класс `А` и класс `B`, наследующий класс `A`. Кто подскажет функцию, выдающую `True` или `False` на наследование классом `B` класса `A`?

Comment: [`issubclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#issubclass)

Comment: @hoefling, напишите ответ. В нем желательно добавить чем это отличается от isinstance

Answer (score 9):

Встроенные функции `issubclass` и `isinstance` отвечают на вопрос о наследовании:

- [*issubclass (class, classinfo)*](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#issubclass) - является ли класс унаследованым (дочерним) от другого(их) класса(ов)
- [*isinstance (object, classinfo)*](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#isinstance) - является ли объект сущностью класса(ов)

```py
class A: pass
class B(A): pass

issubclass (B, A)
# True
issubclass (A, B)
# False
isinstance (B(), A)
# True
```

Но, не путайте:

```py
isinstance (B, A)
# False
```

Класс `B` унаследован от `A`, но он не является его сущностью. Классы сами по себе объекты и функция `isinstance` к ним применима. Класс `B` является сущностью класса `type`, который в свою очередь, унаследован от `object`, поэтому:

```py
isinstance (B, object)
# True
```

Answer (score 2):

```
issublclass(B, A)
```

Это точно функция, которую вы хотите. См. [документацию для этой функции](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#issubclass).